# 2 ideal op amp circuit design, find voltage Vp

Tags: operational-amplifier

I need to find Vp giving the values below. These two opamps are ideal with negligible current input to them. I'm doing KCL across the circuit and then switching to voltage/resistance but I'm not getting the right answer.[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. There is a schematic button on the editor toobar that will enable you to do a professional looking schematic. Leave the original there or it will make @TonyStewart look as though he can't draw a neat diagram.

Comment: Show us Your calculations.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

> (Edit R1/(R1+R2)= k3 should be 2/3 not 1/3 and makes only minor changes to Vp) Thanks to @G36 but this is still correct simplified approach.

Oh I see it's homework. (hint was ideal OA's)

Not so simple with 2 feedback loops.

R7 limits current but not gain,  k1=R6/R5=6.91, k2=R3/R4=2.78, k3 =R1/(R1+R2)=1/3 . The U2  introduces offset ( Vp) which also affects U1 out.

- Vo=k1* (Vp-Vi)  or \$Vp= \dfrac{Vo+k1*Vi}{k1} \$
- Vp=k2k3* Vo=\$ \dfrac{Vo+k1*Vi}{k1} \$ thus \$Vo =Vi*\dfrac{k1}{(k1*k2*k3)-1}=\$
  .....

Good luck , I think answer is 768mV... But it's definitely < 1V.

### PROOF

Your Equivalent Circuit with gain blocks for each stage except for U1, R6/R5 ratio = k1 then U2 gain=k2,  R1/(R1+R2) = k3,

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVg3AN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The solution to the problem must match Vin+ to Vp for ideal OA's have 0V differential (virtual gnd).

### Intuitive answer

**If k1R is removed**, then Vp = Vi (ok?) = Vin+ ( 0v diff) then **Vo=(-)Vi** due to 0V Gnd reference.  Removing k1 causes an infinite negative feedback loop like and unity gain non-inverting amp.

**if kiR is shorted then Vp=Vin+=Vo=0V(gnd)**

Therefore Vp must lie between 0 and Vin+ for any value of k1, k2 k3 due to ideal gain of U1 in the loop regardless of k2 , k3  ( k*0=0, k*∞=∞) which are distractions that serve no real purpose but may simulate real systems.

### comments

- R9 = 91 is irrelevant since ideal OA can drive any current and does not attenuate any signals.
- this answer relies on learning the equations for k of an inverting OA and learning Control System transfer function reduction for simple solution. Otherwise KVL gets big... which can be done, but I'm not going to try Mathjax on it... ;)

Ask any Control System Prof to validate. I am very confident it is correct.

Comment: Sorry it's a practice problem out of the book. I just didn't word it currently. I need to find the voltage at Vp

Comment: Can you show me how you solved for it?

Comment: **See blue font above for  answers on how to solve.**  but 91 ohm is current limited from Op Amp so only small swing allowed or you must buffer it like an emitter follower inside feedback loop

Comment: "I think answer is 768mV..." not likely to be correct.

Comment: "But its definitely < 1V." not even remotely correct.

Comment: The bottom cct is a negative feedback loop making overall  a less than unity gain inverting amplifier.  Your comments are  definitely incorrect.  THink about it again pls.

Comment: If for example, I assume that Vo = 1V I can found Vp as a Vp = -R3/R4*R1/(R1+R2)*1V = -2.78*2/3*1V = -1.853V and Vin = -2.265V. Hence we can define the gain Vp/Vin = -1.853V/-2.265V = 0.818 V/V. So, the voltage at Vp for Vin = - 3.4V is -2.78V

Comment: @G36, dannyf  .... Final answer is here using same R Ratios agrees with my conclusions. http://tinyurl.com/yagopml9  Vp=767mV  Vo=-0.823V  Av=Vo/Vi= -0.823

Comment: The ratio R1/(R1+R2) = 1.6kΩ/(1.6kΩ + 0.801kΩ) ≈ 2/3 not 1/3

Comment: Thanks for correction but not much difference on Vp still <1V  Vp=817mV , but Av=-0.449 reduces still <-1
 Av= - http://tinyurl.com/y7seobcv.  I am still very confident in my solution approach

Comment: But I still don't understand why my conclusion is wrong?

Comment: I now agree with you  Vp/Vin = -1.853V/-2.265V = 0.818  so Vp=818mV vs my 817mV in rounding differences. THanks for validating my answer, but yours is simpler.

Comment: G36: "So, the voltage at Vp for Vin = - 3.4V is -2.78V" that's the correct answer.

Comment: that's the method of analysis used by G36 for ratios. THe **correct answer is for Vi=1V , Vp = 817mV** and Vp is always < Vin and in this case always <1V as I indicated.  I think your method is OK  and mine gives the same result. Recall initially you had Vp as a much larger value.   I chose the control system method because it is useless as an Op Amp design, but your method , now, is better

Answer (score 1):

fairly simple.

the lower opamp's inverting input is at ground. current flowing through R4 is Vo / R4, and it will create a negative voltage on the lower opamp's output, -Vo/R4 * R3.

That voltage is being split between a voltage divider R2/R1. so Vp = -Vo/R4 * R3 * R1 / (R1 + R2).

The upper opamp's two input terminals must be at the same potential, from that you will get another equation between Vp and Vo.

done.

edit: so let me finish as the other poster seems to struggle too much in getting to the right answer.

From the above, Vp = -Vo/R4 * R3 * R1 / (R1 + R2) = -1.85 Vo = -k Vo.

That means U1's inverting input sits at -kVo. So the current through R6, from right to left, must be (Vo - (-kVo)) / R6 = 3Vo / R6.

That same current flows through R5: (-kVo - Vin) / R5. Working out the math and you have

-Vin / R5 = Vo (3/R6 + k/R5).

plugging in all the numbers that you got

Vo = -(-3.4v) / 680R / (3 / 4.7K + 1.85 / 680R) = 1.49v.
Vp = - k Vo = -1.85 * 1.49v= -2.76v.

unfortunately all it takes is elementary school-level math. No professor of any kind is required.

Comment: not as simple as I thought.... Since U1 has an offset so it's output Vo is  (Vp-Vi)*R6/R5  then lower Vo(U2) sets Vp. If R6 is removed Vo=-Vi  and if R6 is shorted Vo~0V  so Vp is always between 0 and ~-Vi.